# AccessDeniedException: User is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm trying to invoke a lambda function from node.

```js
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
    accessKeyId: 'id',
    secretAccessKey: 'key',
    region: 'us-west-2'
});

lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'test1',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({
        key1: 'Arjun',
        key2: 'kom',
        key3: 'ath'
    })
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else     console.log(data);
});
```

The keys are for an IAM user. The user has `AWSLambdaExecute` and `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policies attached.

I get a permission error:
`AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::1221321312:user/cli is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:1221321312:function:test1`

I read the docs and several blogs, but I'm unable to authorise this user to invoke the lambda function. How do get this user to invoke lambda?

Comment: I heartily wish there were an aws cli or web interface to fix this.


aws add-access "AccessDeniedException: User: ARN... is not authorized to perform: ACTION on resource: ARN..."


maybe prompt you with a couple of description questions and add the access roles.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

### UPDATE (TL;DR)

There is now also an IAM Managed Policy named `AWSLambdaRole` that you can assign to your IAM user or IAM role. This should give you the permissions you need.

---

### Original Answer

The `AWSLambdaExecute` and `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` do not provide the permissions that are being expressed in the error. Both of these managed policies are designed to be attached to your Lambda function itself, so **it runs** with these policies.

The error is saying the user under which the nodejs program is running does not have rights to start the Lambda function.

You need to give your IAM user the `lambda:InvokeFunction` permission:

1. Find your User in the IAM Management Console and click it.
2. On the "Permissions" tab, expand the "Inline Policies" section and click the "click here" link to add a policy".
3. Select a "Custom Policy".
4. Give your policy a name. It can be anything.
5. Put this policy in the Policy Document field.

Sample policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1464440182000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this policy, I have included both methods to invoke lambda methods.

Comment: This did not work for me, I had to use "lambda:*". In other words had to hit it with a big hammer!

Comment: For what you are doing, there's no need to create a custom policy. You can add AWSLambdaRole as a managed policy on the user profile and that's it.

Comment: I tried both adding custom policy and attaching "AWSLambdaRole", but I am still getting the AccessDeniedException: <USER> is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction

Comment: @lusocoding that worked for me, let me know if you post it as an answer of its own ;)

Comment: Works for me but it took some minutes to an hour before the changes took effect

Comment: AWSLambdaRole didn't work for me, i needed to create the inline policy with lambda:InvokeAsync, since i have event function types

Comment: the Action "lambda:InvokeAsync" is deprecated, you just need the "lambda:InvokeFunction"

Comment: Adding `AWSLambdaRole` worked for me, but it took a few minutes to wait for it to work

Comment: This is the perfect example of Amazon's trash UI. Or, to put it more clearly, why don't they just SAY this?!

Comment: WARNING: Using `"Resource": "*"` has given me a ton of trouble. better to use `"arn:aws:lambda:*:*:*"` instead

Answer (score 21):

I'm using [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/blog/build-a-serverless-rest-api/), and I had to also add `arn:aws:lambda` as a resource in my serverless.yml in order to use `lambda.invoke`.

```yaml
 iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - lambda:InvokeFunction # Added this like mentioned above
      Resource:
        - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:*
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:*:* # Had to add this too
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me (none of the other answers worked for me).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Just a note that this config should be put under the "provider" section, https://forum.serverless.com/t/generate-iam-permissions-for-invoking-lambda-from-lambda/338

Comment: Not necessarily, it can be declared under the function yml definition as well in iamRoleStatements

Answer (score 12):

This solution worked for me:

1. Attaching ***AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser*** policy from the
   policy list (without that I got an error on "iam:listRole")
2. Adding ***lambda:ListFunctions*** to the custom policy defined by
   [@Matt Houser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37499226/13914780)

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1464440182000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Go to [IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home?#/users), select the user and click on *"add permissions"*.
In the list of permission , you can simply search with all those policies with lambda,and check the ones you want in order to execute the lambda from console.

[image: enter AWS IAM permissions]

Answer (score 4):

If you just use the policies that AWS provides you have to give to the user or the group it belongs 
[image: Policy from AWS]

Comment: Adding` AWSCodeDeploy` worked form me when calling Lambda from iOS.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding the `AWSLambdaFullAccess` permissions to the user.

1. Within IAM Users, click add permissions
2. Select "Attach existing policies directly"
3. Search for `AWSLambdaFullAccess`, select it and click `next:review` at the bottom of the page.
4. Click `Add Permissions`

And that should do it.

Comment: I had to add "AWSCodeDeployRoleForLambda"

Comment: Agree with @KeithNorman, AWSLambdaFullAccess alone didn't do it for me.

Comment: note AWSLambdaFullAccess & AWSLambdaReadOnlyAccess are now deprecated. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/security_iam_troubleshoot.html#security_iam_troubleshoot-admin-deprecation

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
{
    "Sid": "PermissionToInvoke",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:*:*"
}
```

Comment: What is it about the Sid? Is this arbitrary?

Comment: @Cadoiz You put a unique name in the Sid for identification of that permission from others

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow one lambda function to invoke another one you should update policies of your lambda role.

**This is a `Terraform` example:**

Set Up the IAM Roles and Policies:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_1_role" {
    name   = "Lambda_1_Role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Add IAM Policy:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy_for_lambda_1" {
    name         = "aws_iam_policy_for_terraform_aws_lambda_1_role"
    path         = "/"
    description  = "AWS IAM Policy for managing aws lambda 1 role"
    policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1464440182000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:InvokeAsync",
            "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*" 
        ]
    }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

*Don't forget to specify your Resource. Don't use the wildcard for production.*

Attach IAM Policy to IAM Role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_iam_policy_to_iam_role_lambda_1" {
    role        = aws_iam_role.lambda_1_role.name
    policy_arn  = aws_iam_policy.iam_policy_for_lambda_1.arn
}
```

Create a lambda:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_1" {
    function_name  = "Lambda_1"
    filename       = "../lambda-1.zip"
    role           = aws_iam_role.lambda_1_role.arn
    handler        = "index.handler"
    runtime        = "nodejs16.x"
    depends_on     = [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.attach_iam_policy_to_iam_role_lambda_1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For SAM templates, make sure you have added the lambda resource to your AppSync resource:

```
AppSyncApiServicePolicy:
Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
Properties:
  PolicyName: AppSyncLambdaInvokePolicy
  Roles:
    - !Ref AppSyncApiServiceRole
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Resource:
          - !GetAtt GetMessages.Arn // added lambda resource
          - !GetAtt SendMessage.Arn // added lambda resource
```

Answer (score 0):

For running lambda functions from CloudWatch alarm: you should add resouce-based policy in your lambda configuration and the principal should be **`lambda.alarms.cloudwatch.amazonaws.com`**.
These principals didn't work for me:

- `cloudwatch.amazonaws.com`
- `logs.amazonaws.com`