# How to invoke an existing AWS Lambda function from laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke an existing aws-lambda function from my php code in laravel to get the data and save in my database. 
The actual command I want to invoke is the following:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name expo2020-metrics --region eu-west-3 response.json
```

Here is the code I'm using to invoke my function:

```
use Aws\Lambda\LambdaClient;use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;

$credentials = new Credentials('YOUR_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY');
    $client = LambdaClient::factory(array(
        'credentials' => $credentials,
        'region' => 'eu-west-3',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ));
    $result = $client->getFunction(array(
        'FunctionName' => 'expo2020-metrics',
    ));
```

But I'm getting the following response:

> `{"Message":"User: arn:aws:iam::677537359471:user/customer/expo2020-metrics is not authorized to perform: lambda: GetFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:677537359471:function:expo2020-metrics"}`

I'm not sure that I'm using the right code to invoke the function or not. I am using the PHP sdk provided by AWS.

Comment: Take a look if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498124/accessdeniedexception-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-lambdainvokefunction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `getFunction` which just gives you information about the Lambda function. That is not equivalent to the `aws lambda invoke` CLI command you are trying to translate into PHP.

You should be calling [the invoke() function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Lambda.LambdaClient.html#_invoke) of the Lambda client.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code on Gist: https://gist.github.com/robinvdvleuten/e7259939267ad3eb1dfdc20a344cc94a.

```php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Lambda\LambdaClient;

$client = LambdaClient::factory([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
     ]
]);

$result = $client->invoke([
    'FunctionName' => 'hello-world',
]);

var_dump($result->get('Payload'));
```