# 403 on ChangeResourceRecordSets despite the role having route53Domains:* in the policy

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

The error

```
User: arn:aws:sts::[redacted]:assumed-role/laravel-vapor-role/vapor-[redacted]-platform-staging-queue is not authorized to perform: route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets on resource: arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/[redacted]
```

My role

```
{
  "permissionsBoundary": {},
  "roleName": "laravel-vapor-role",
  "policies": [
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": [
              "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
              "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
              "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:FilterLogEvents",
              "logs:PutLogEvents",
              "ssm:GetParameters",
              "ssm:GetParameter",
              "lambda:invokeFunction",
              "s3:*",
              "ses:*",
              "sqs:*",
              "dynamodb:*",
              "route53domains:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "laravel-vapor-role-policy",
      "type": "inline"
    }
  ],
  "trustedEntities": [
    "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: try to see that is same problem but not aws. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498124/accessdeniedexception-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-lambdainvokefunction)

Comment: Thanks, but any idea what's wrong with mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your policy **does not include** route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets:

> Grants permission to create, update, or delete a record, which contains authoritative DNS information for a specified domain or subdomain name

You only have `"route53domains:*"` permissions, but you **don't have** `route53:*` nor `route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets`.

`ChangeResourceRecordSets` is from `route53`, not from `route53domains`.